# Minimum Hardware Requirement For Setting Up OpenSSL Certificate Authority in Linux

Tags: linux, security, openssl, certificate-authority

I've been seeing a lot of [OpenSSL Certificate Authority](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/introduction.html) "how tos" for Linux, but if I plan to create our own Certificate Authority for a WAN network both externally and internally...

- What is the **minimum hardware requirements** for setting up an OpenSSL Certificate Authority server?
- Does the Certificate Authority need to be **replicated** or can it just be one single server?

Comment: A trivially tiny amount of disk space? Depends on how many certificates you want to issue, I suppose.

Comment: I'm planning to issue around 5-30 certificates only for now, but may grow up to around 100.

Comment: Make sure you have a good entropy source. As for the replicated part, if you loose the CA private key you may have problems... It may even be recommended to offload the key for security reasons and to keep only a subCA online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn’t. If you have a Linux install working with more than 0% disk space you should be fine

Comment: What about the processors? How fast should it be?

Comment: Not important. If you’re running the OS. It’s not like Windows where you need to be wary of system requirements. You’re running a command line based tool. It’s not doing anything horrendously demanding.

Answer (score 2):

Run a benchmark, see for yourself it that performance is sufficient:

`openssl speed rsa2048`

For storage, you will need about 4KiB per certificate, and depending on how many certificates you will be revoking, between few KiB to 20MiB for the CRL.

That being said, I would recommend strongly against using raw `openssl` for running a production CA. Its defaults are... specific... and it's *extremely* easy to shoot yourself in the foot with it (do you know which KeyUse and Extended Key Use flags should your certificates have?). It's a debugging tool, not a production interface to `libcrypto.so` and definitely not one to `libssl.so`.

I'd suggest using [Dogtag](http://www.dogtagpki.org/wiki/PKI_Main_Page) or even better, [FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page) for a full managed system.

Answer (score 1):

A minimum functional command line only openssl CA requires almost nothing relatively speaking.  The keys and certificate database for ~100 certs would be less the 100k of storage.

Your key/cert generation and signing might be a bit slow if you use really low end processor.  But this only impacts creation/generation of keys/certs.

It isn't generally a good idea, but if you plan on using this same system as a distribution point for your certificate revocation lists, then you would need enough resources to run a minimal web server that can serve out static files.  But this really shouldn't require much either.

If you want to use one of those fancy web-based certificate authority [e.g. EJBCA](https://www.ejbca.org/) then your resource requirements will go up dramatically.

I dislike using the cli tools alone, so you might want to have enough resources to run something like [xca](http://hohnstaedt.de/xca/).  Which still doesn't require much.